# How to make a sparql query inside another sparql query?

Tags: sparql

I am trying to make a sparql query inside another sparql query. In sql, we can do it like this:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (SELECT STATEMENT);
```

I want to do the same thing in SPARQL query. Specifically I have two sparql queries and I want to combine them together. My end goal is to find 'Siemens PLM Software Company's subsidiaries. In order to do this, first i need to find the company's id and then look for its subsidiaries.

Q1: Finds the unique identity of 'Siemens PLM Software Company'

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?label ?articleLabel  WHERE {
  ?item ?label "Siemens PLM Software"@en;
    wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453.
  ?article schema:about ?item;
    schema:inLanguage "en".
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

- Returns Q15898201

Q2: Find the subsidiary of 'Siemens PLM Software Company'

```
 SELECT ?Subsidiary ?SubsidiaryLabel ?parent_organization ?parent_organizationLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?Subsidiary wdt:P749 wd:Q15898201.
  OPTIONAL { ?Subsidiary wdt:P749 ?parent_organization. }
```

- Returns Siemens

I would like to combine them together to something like this:

```
SELECT ?Subsidiary ?SubsidiaryLabel ?parent_organization ?parent_organizationLabel WHERE {
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
      ?Subsidiary wdt:P749 wd:
{SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?label ?articleLabel  WHERE {
      ?item ?label "Siemens PLM Software"@en;
        wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453.
      ?article schema:about ?item;
        schema:inLanguage "en".
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
    }
}.
      OPTIONAL { ?Subsidiary wdt:P749 ?parent_organization. }
```

Do you have any idea how can i do this? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use subqueries? Why not just combining the triple patterns of both queries? I mean in the end it will be a join and nothing more is need here. No need for subquery here

Comment: I used the answer from @cygri, and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were several things not quite clear:

- Did you really mean to return the `rdfs:label` property as `?label`? I don't understand why you'd want to do that, so I assume you mean to just directly match on the `rdfs:label` property without returning it
- Why return `?articleLabel`? It's not a real label anyway but just the value of `?label` as a literal. I assume you mean to just return `?article`.
- It seems you have the parent organization relationship backwards? Your Q2 asks for subsidiaries of Siemens PLM Software. None exist. To ask for Siemens, you need to ask for

  ```
  wd:Q15898201 wdt:P749 ?parent_organization
  ```

  and not

  ```
  ?Subsidiary wdt:P749 wd:Q15898201
  ```

With that out of the way: There is no need for a subquery here. The query can be achieved simply by writing out the graph pattern for the desired graph structure, using `OPTIONAL` for parts that may not exist, and making sure that the variable names match up correctly throughout the query:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?parent_organization ?parent_organizationLabel WHERE {

  # Find business by label
  ?item rdfs:label "Siemens PLM Software"@en;
    wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453.

  # Find English-language articles about the business
  ?article schema:about ?item;
    schema:inLanguage "en".

  # Find the business' parent organization, if one exists
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P749 ?parent_organization. }   

  # For any variable ?xxx, add variable ?xxxLabel with the label
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

That being said, you *can* use a subquery if you really want to:

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?parent_organization ?parent_organizationLabel WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?item {
      ?item rdfs:label "Siemens PLM Software"@en;
      wdt:P31 wd:Q4830453.
    }
  }
  ?article schema:about ?item;
    schema:inLanguage "en".
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P749 ?parent_organization. }   
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

This is equivalent to the first query, but runs much slower because the query optimiser is not as good at handling subqueries.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for your help, i am new to sparql and still trying to understand how its working. This input was really useful for me.